# Probability of a sample mean for a bivariate probability density function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The bivariate probability density function for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ equals the following: $f(x,y)=12x^2y^3$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$; 
$f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Suppose you take a random sample of size $n=50$ for the random variable $X$. Find the probability that the sample mean of $X$ will be greater than $0.7$.

I found $X$ and $Y$ are independent since $f_X(x)f_Y(x)=f(x,y)$. However, I can't figure out how to find the probability the sample mean of $X$ will be greater than $0.7$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/18398), but did you mean $f_Y(y)$ instead of $f_Y(x)$?

Comment: Did you mean $f_Y(y)$ instead of $f_Y(x)$?

Comment: You have not responded to my question, despite being logged in in the mean time.  I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking."

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y) = 12x^2y^3$; $0 < x < 1$; $0 <y < 1$

Integrating over $y$ to get PDF of $X$:

$f_X(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y)dy = 3x^2$

Similarly, $f_Y(y) = 4y^3$

Probability that sample mean of $n=50$ samples from X is greater than 0.7 = 1 - Probability that each sample is less than 0.7

Hence, require probability = $1-(F_X(x \leq 0.7))^{50} = 1-(0.7)^{150}$